# Laravel 5.3 Password Reset error without any error log

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm using the default laravel auth method.
When I try to reset a password, everything work fine until i try to send the reset form.

At this moment, it just send me an error with any log.
I know an error is sent because I added the following line to `App\Exceptions\handler.php`

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    Artisan::call('sms:basic');

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

So, I'm recieving the notification that an error occured. I'm not logged in and the new password is not working.

When this happen, the laravel.log file is empty. So I don't know why is not working.

There is the route I use:

```
Auth::routes();
```

There is the view file.

```
@extends('layouts.public')

@section('content')

        <!-- RESET FORM -->
        <!--===================================================-->
        <div class="cls-content">
            <div class="cls-content-sm panel">
                <div class="panel-body background-black fix-margin-top">
                    <div class="text-left"><img style="height: 90px; width: auto;margin-left: -25px;" src="{{ url('/img/logoTorqueWhite.svg') }}" alt="" class=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cls-content-sm panel ">
                <div class="panel-body fix-margin-top">
                    <div class="pull-right"><a class="black" href="{{ url('/') }}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 vert-line">
                            <p>Réinitialiser votre mot de passe</p>
                            @if (session('status'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    {{ session('status') }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            <form method="POST" role="form" action="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                                <div class="form-group text-left{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <label>Courriel</label>
                                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="form-control">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group text-left{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <label>Mot de passe</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="form-control">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group text-left{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <label>Confirmer le mot de passe</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                    @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                        <span class="form-control">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
                                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                                        <input name="reset" type="submit" class="btn btn-torque" value="RÉINITIALISER">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="valign text-right">
                                <p>Contactez-nous<br>
                                (819) 679-2944<br>
                                info@torquemanagement.ca</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-left">
                        {{--<div class="col-xs-12">
                        Vous avez oublié votre mot de passe? <a href="/password/reset">Cliquez ici</a><br>
                        Vous n'avez pas encore de compte Torque? Créé un compte
                        </div>--}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--===================================================-->
@endsection
```

I saw somewhere else someone asking to add this route:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    dd ( bcrypt('raw_password') == "encrypted_password_in_db");
});
```

It return me false and the guys was saying it suppose to return true.
There was no other explanation about this, but maybe it can help you helping me. I don't really know what this is suppose to mean.

Comment: Did you try resetting password after logging in?

Comment: I'm logged out when I try to reset. I can change password while i'm logging with a custom change password form.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a new password use

`Hash::make('newpassword')`

After it will work:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    dd (Hash::check('raw_password', 'encrypted-password'));
});
```

The Laravel use always a random salted password, so you can't check it with ==

Comment: When I try your line of code, I got false as result.

Comment: Also, I tought the security of Hashids is lower then bcrypt? You can do an Hash::decode('anything'), instead when you use bcrypt, there is no built-in decode for it.